# Como tirar o scroll de um campo input date?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um campo input date, quando mudo a data e continuo com o foco no campo, se usar o scroll, a data muda. Preciso desabilitar esse scroll quando o campo tiver selecionado.

Comment: Aqui não tenho esse comportamento... Qual é o Browser e o Sistema operacional que vc está tendo esse problema?

Comment: Windows, Google Chrome

Comment: Não meu não faz isso... Vc está usando trackpad ou um mouse convencional com rodinha?

Comment: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date)

neste exemplo mesmo da para ver, se voce selecionar o ano, por exemplo, e usar o scroll do mouse, o ano vai mudar

estou usando um mouse convencional com rodinha

Comment: se o foco estiver no dia, ou no mes, acontece neles tbm

Comment: Testando localmente isso não acontece comingo no Win10 usando Chrome, mas lá no exemplo deles no site quando eu coloco no campo ele faz mesmo esse Scroll... vc está testando isso direto no site deles ou no seu projeto vc tb está com esse comportamento? Pois lá eles podem estar usando algum script que altera o comportamento padrão...

Comment: no meu projeto eu também estou com este comportamento!! e preciso tirar esse scroll de todos os inputs date pq estou tendo problemas com os usuários

Comment: Existe um script no W3Schools que habilita o scroll no campo. Esse scroll não funciona no Chrome nem em qualquer outro navegador. Talvez vc esteja usando uma versão desatualizada do Chrome.

Comment: Não tem como saber facilmente. Teria que destrinchar o código-fonte deles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá pra tentar resolver com javascript

```js
$('#seuForm').on('focus', 'input[type=date]', function (e) {
  $(this).on('mousewheel.disableScroll', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  })
})
```

```css
*{font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;}
input[type=date] {display: block;margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="seuform" action="/action_page.php">
  Teste: <input type="date" name="teste">
  Teste 2: <input type="date" name="teste2">
  Teste 4: <input type="date" name="teste3">
  Teste 5: <input type="date" name="teste4">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Poderia colocar um exemplo com JavaScript puro, porque não se sabe se a autora da pergunta usa jQuery.

Comment: Sugiro explicar o que foi feito no código.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você pode desativar o padrão de entrada do campo `input="date"` com *JavaScript*, por exemplo.

```js
let campoInput = window.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=date]");
for(let i = 0; i < campoInput.length; i++){
  campoInput[i].addEventListener("wheel", function(event)
  {
     event.preventDefault();
  })
}
```

```css
label {display: block;margin-top:10px}
```

```html
<label for="campo1">Campo 1</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="campo1">
<label for="campo2">Campo 2</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="campo2">
<label for="campo3">Campo 3</label>
<input type="date" name="" id="campo3">
```

No trecho de código em cima temos uma variável `campoInput` que seleciona todos os `input` tipo `date` e os coloca em um array e nele é adicionado um evento com o `addEventListener` e o evento é `wheel` que é disparado quando a roda do mouse é rolada. E depois chamará uma função anônima desativando o padrão de entrada do campo `input="date"` que é rolar o scroll do mouse e alterar a data.

Uma forma melhor de fazer esse script é com o laço `for each`, porém, não suportado em alguns navegadores como o IE. Segue:

```
let campoInput = window.document.querySelectorAll("input[type=date]");

campoInput.forEach(input =>{
    input.addEventListener("wheel", function(event);
})
```

Comment: Desnecessário colocar um id no campo apenas para isso. Pode pegar pelo type.

Comment: Sim, também, mas o mais comum é você pegar por id ou class, mas também funciona e fica de opção.

Comment: Acredito que um código mais enxuto seja melhor, menos bytes a serem carregados. Além do que, embora a autora cita "um campo" no título da pergunta, e nos comentários ela diz "todos os campos", ou seja, com id não dá pra fazer isso em mais de um campo, a não ser que ela coloque um id em cada campo, o que torna inviável fazer isso usando id. Mas tudo bem. Sua solução não é todo ruim, mas tb não é o ideal.

Comment: Bom, eu vim pela pergunta e não pelos comentários e na pergunta da autora estava aparentemente que o problema era em apenas em um único input e não em vários input. Então o erro não foi meu e sim da autora que fez a pergunta, pois eu respondi com clareza e resolvendo o problema da pergunta. E sim eu também concordo com você, como diz você "Acredito que um código mais enxuto seja melhor", mas esse código é apropriado sim a pergunta dela, mas não ao comentário dela :).

Comment: Seria mais melhor então a autora editar a pergunta e colocar no plural e não no singular.

Comment: O problema é que esse "um" na pergunta pode ter dupla interpretação: pode ser um pronome ou um número. :/ Se for pronome, é indefinido, que pode ser 1 ou mais campos.

Comment: Editei sua resposta, dando uma forma de usar seu script em todos os campos do tipo `date` como ela pediu.

Comment: Ok, vou aceitar, valeu!